# IPv4 address changes automatically

Tags: windows, networking, ip, static-ip-address

I run a website on my computer using XAMP. It runs on port 8888, when I configure the port I need complete this ip: 10.0.0._ to my IPV4 which is 10.0.0.4 right now.

I don't know why but my IPV4 is keep changing which means that every time it changes I have to re-configure the port.

How can I change the IPV4 from dynamic ip to static? I guess it somewhere over here:
[image]

Comment: This belong to [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @Qben why, why it's not belongs to here?

Comment: The question does not have anything to do with programming. To see what kind of question belong to SO you might want to read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what you input into the third window in your picture you would just click the radio button using the following ip address then type in the address you wanted (10.0.0.4 or something like that) then if you hit tab it should automatically fill in your subnet mask if it doesn't it's probably 255.255.255.0 and then fill in your default gateway, if you have default configuration set up it will probably be 10.0.0.1 .